# Error conetar PhpMyAdmin y Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo un error al tratar de abrir mi phpmyadmin me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revise la consola de xamp y al intentar empezar el servicio mysqli me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abri el error.log de MySQL y me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que un dato importate es que nunca le he puesto contraseña solo abria 'http://localhost/phpmyadmin/' Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola a mi me pasaba algo similar porque el puerto que utiliza mysql ya estaba en uso, para solucionarlo tuve que cambiar el puerto a 3307.

tienes que entrar a tu archivo my.ini y donde diga port=3306 cámbialo a port=3307

Comment: Gracias, pero no me sirvio igualmente te agradezco :)